# ScrollView is not Scrolling completely in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, scrollview

I am developing an application in which I am using scrollView in an activity. The scrollview is scrolling but not displaying complete **contents. It is not displaying last three contents of the View. This is my complete code. The last three textView from the code TextView32, TextView33, TextView34 is not displaying**. Please give me solution for this.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Sacraments" >  

 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/com"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:text="@string/c"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="@string/c1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="@string/c2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:text="@string/d"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:text="@string/d1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="@string/d2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="@string/e"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
        android:text="@string/e1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView7"
        android:text="@string/e2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="@string/g"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView11"
        android:text="@string/g1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView10"
        android:text="@string/g2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/i"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView14"
        android:text="@string/i1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView16"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView14"
        android:text="@string/i2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView17"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:text="@string/sa"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView18"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView17"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView17"
        android:text="@string/sa1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView19"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView18"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView18"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView16"
        android:text="@string/sa2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView20"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView18"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView18"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:text="@string/sv"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView21"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView20"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView20"
        android:text="@string/sv1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView22"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView21"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView21"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView19"
        android:text="@string/sv2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView23"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView21"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView21"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:text="@string/t"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView24"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView23"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView23"
        android:text="@string/t1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView25"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView24"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView24"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView22"
        android:text="@string/t2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView26"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView24"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView24"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:text="@string/tt"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView27"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView26"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView26"
        android:text="@string/tt1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView28"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView27"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView27"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView25"
        android:text="@string/tt2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView29"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView27"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView27"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:text="@string/ttt"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView30"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView29"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView29"
        android:text="@string/ttt1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView31"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView30"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView30"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView28"
        android:text="@string/ttt2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView32"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView30"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView30"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:text="@string/x"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView33"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView32"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView32"
        android:text="@string/x1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView34"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView33"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView33"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView31"
        android:text="@string/x2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />


</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Not scrolling after XAVERITIES

Comment: I dont know if what you are doing is right as a design pattern. Shouldnt you use a `ListView` and supply an adapter ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace your xml code with this....

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Sacraments" >  

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/com"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="none" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1">



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:text="@string/c"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:text="@string/c1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:text="@string/c2"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:text="@string/d"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
    android:text="@string/d1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:text="@string/d2"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:text="@string/e"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
    android:text="@string/e1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView7"
    android:text="@string/e2"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView11"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:text="@string/g"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView12"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView11"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView11"
    android:text="@string/g1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView13"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView12"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView12"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView10"
    android:text="@string/g2"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView14"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView12"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView12"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/i"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView15"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView14"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView14"
    android:text="@string/i1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView16"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView13"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView14"
    android:text="@string/i2"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView17"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView15"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView15"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:text="@string/sa"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView18"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView17"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView17"
    android:text="@string/sa1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView19"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView18"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView18"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView16"
    android:text="@string/sa2"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView20"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView18"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView18"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:text="@string/sv"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView21"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView20"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView20"
    android:text="@string/sv1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView22"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView21"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView21"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView19"
    android:text="@string/sv2"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView23"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView21"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView21"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:text="@string/t"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView24"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView23"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView23"
    android:text="@string/t1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView25"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView24"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView24"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView22"
    android:text="@string/t2"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView26"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView24"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView24"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:text="@string/tt"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView27"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView26"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView26"
    android:text="@string/tt1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView28"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView27"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView27"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView25"
    android:text="@string/tt2"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView29"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView27"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView27"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:text="@string/ttt"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView30"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView29"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView29"
    android:text="@string/ttt1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView31"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView30"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView30"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView28"
    android:text="@string/ttt2"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView32"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView30"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView30"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:text="@string/x"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView33"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView32"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView32"
    android:text="@string/x1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView34"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView33"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView33"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView31"
    android:text="@string/x2"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />


</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What did you do differently and why?

Answer (score 0):

Check below lines and replace and try,

```
<ScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```